# firebase cloud functions firestore trigger onUpdate read cost

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, triggers, google-cloud-functions

Good evening from somewhere in pacific area! [: Using firebase platform is really a wonderful experience for baby flutter devs like me, since the team provides well-described dev friendly docs and integrated products for various needs. Though feeling blessed with all these products, i've recently encountered a question on the pricing policy of cloud functions - firestore trigger integration(still marked as beta in build docs).

Single firestore document size limit is 1MiB. Not to receive maxSizeOverflowing error, it is important to keep tracking size of each document in firestore. In case of mine, size of a single data input from client's request is fixed to approximately 1kB.

So i'm planning to create a core field called `counter` in each document, and for safety, when value of `counter` is larger than 900, the operation would detour the original plan and then make a new document, store request's data to the new document. It would make every requests free from sizeOverflowingException and help all documents' size to be less than 1MiB. And here comes the question.

In order to know how every single document size is going on, we need to read the value of the `counter` which is updated each time user send a request(approx 1kB). IMO, `onUpdate` trigger would be a cool solution. We can get both `change.before.data()` and `change.after.data()`.

Q: In case of getting those data with normal calls like flutterfire library, 2-read-cost will be required. But i couldn't find any information for the cost of `onUpdate` trigger which is actually 'reading' different data. IMO again, it should cost same 2-read-cost since the trigger consumes two different states of a single document, but couldn't find any article making clear of pricing policy for this situation. If the trigger only costs its own fee(ex. cloud functions invocation fee), we can thankfully save 2-read-cost by using `if (change.before.data().counter >= 900) { // set a new document then save current request's data in there }`, which otherwise would be spent on client's every request only to figure out the value of `counter`.
***So, i hope to exactly know if cloud functions onUpdate trigger's before.data() and after.data() are subject to read cost of $0.06/100K.***

If our service grows on and on, saving 2-read-cost by using `cloud functions onUpdate trigger` instead of 2 normal reading operations would benefit us a lot. I tried to write the question as clear as possible, but i think there can be things still left unclear. I'd really appreciate if anyone leave comments for the unclear parts.

I think there would be a huge cost advantage if the trigger is not subject to reading pricing policy, since we can migrate client-side operations to cloud functions for reducing reading costs purpose. Hope any firebase guru could find out this question! Thank you in advance [:

Comment: Pricing questions and overall app design questions are a bit off topic for SO but more importantly, the question seems to revolve around document size. Without understanding why you're running into that limit it would hard to suggest how to avoid the issue. I suggest updating the question with your document structure and the code you use to read/write it. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Thank you for commenting! In this case, another community member suggested a possible dup SO question, and the q suited my needs. Hope this update also reach to you and i'll review yours too [: